# React Router: How to properly append to route/url without replacing anything?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How do I append to the route with react router?

Let's say the current route is `/page1/page2` and I want to route to `/page1/page2/next-page`

first I get the router

```
const router = useHistory();
```

When I use `push` like this

```
router.push("next-page");
```

It routes to `/page1/next-page`.

When I use add a `/` like this

```
router.push("/next-page");
```

It routes to `/next-page`

I also tried something like this

```
router.push(`${router.location.pathname}/next-page`)
```

But the problem this way is, when I'm currently at `/page1/page2/`, I end up at `/page1/page2//next-page` with two `//`.

Is there a good way to solve this without having to write the complete route like `router.push("/page1/page2/next-page")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is defining a function that removes an `/` form the url if there

```
export const removeSlashSuffix = (input)  => {
    if (input.charAt(input.length - 1) === "/") {
        return input.substr(0, input.length - 1)
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

and then route like this

```
router.push(`${removeSlashSuffix(router.location.pathname)}/nest-page`)
```

This way I get no issues with routes that resolve in url with `//` in it.

This is somewhat of a hacky solution and I wish `react-router-dom` would support this out of the box but it doesn't seem like it does

Answer (score 0):

If you do `router.push("/page1/page2/next-page")`, it should work. I think you need to specify the full path, I don't see anything wrong in doing so

Comment: Thats exact what I don't want to do. I don't want to have to specify the full path because in some situations I don't know the full path, I just want to add something to the existing path

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append something to an existing path, you should be able to do something like

```
const location = useLocation()
const currentPath = location.pathname // to get current route
router.push(`${currentPath}/next-page`)
```

THis is a sudo-code, so you may need to tweak it a bit for proper syntax